# Start process from another process with Multiprocessing library in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, multiprocessing, pyqt5

I'm developing an application with 3 main processes (GUI, process1, process2). The GUI creates process1, and process1 creates process2 (process2 is supposed to start a new QT gui in another window). While process1 is created and working without any trouble, process2 is created but not working, no new QTWidget is created as I want. No error or exception is thrown. Since the project is very large and I cannot write all the code in this question, here is an scheme of the application:

```
class GuiMain(QMainWindow):
    ...
    proc1 = Process1(...)
    proc1.start()
    ...

class Process1(mp.Process)

    def __init__(self, ...):
        mp.Process.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        ...
        proc2 = Process2(...)
        proc2.start()
        ...

class Process2(mp.Process)

    def __init__(self, ...):
        mp.Process.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        # Creating a new QTApplication with MyQTWidget 
        app = QtGui.QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
        ex = rcp_gui.MyQWidget()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())

class MyQWidget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__()
        ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    application = GuiMain()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Am I missing something? Is not possible to start a new QT window from another process than the main one? How can I achieve that?. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does process2 get a PID? If you look at it with a system tool like `ps`, what does it look like? Does its `__init__` method get called? Is there something going on with file handles and process2 blocking when trying to read/write an inherited stdin/stdout?

Comment: I check whether the process gets a PID (the answer is yes), and this lead me to realise that the problem could be some functions related to PyQt5. In Process2 I try to open a new QtWindow, and I don't know if this is possible. So the problem comes from Qt. I'm editing the question

Comment: I have edited the question, I've realised that the problem is when I start the new QT application.

Comment: @edusan1213. I don't see any reason why you can't create a [mcve]. All you need is a toy example that reproduces the problem.